# how to make switch case of enum case (swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, switch-statement, ios8

I got this code from ObjC. I want to convert it to Swift, however, I am having difficulties doing so...

ObjC code :

navgivet.h

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BB3Photo) {
kirkenType = 10 ,
festenType = 20 ,
praestType = 30
};
@property (nonatomic, assign) BB3Photo selectedPhotoType;
```

navgivet.m

```
- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    _selectedPhotoType = button.tag;
}
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vælg Billed"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Vælg fra Biblioteket", @"Vælg Kamera", nil];
sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[sheet showInView:[self.view window]];
```

}

```
switch (_selectedPhotoType) {
    case kirkenType: {
}break;
        case festenType: {
}break;
    case praestType: {
}break;
    default: 
       break;
```

Here's my swift code in this attempt

```
 enum BBPhoto1: Int {
    case kommunen = 10
    case sagsbehandler = 20
    case festen = 30
}
@IBAction func changeImage(sender: AnyObject){
    if sender .isKindOfClass(UIButton){
        let button: UIButton = sender as UIButton
        selectedPhoto = BBPhoto1.fromRaw(button.tag)
    }

    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Billeder", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Vælg fra Biblioteket", "Vælg Kamera")
    actionSheet.showInView(self.view)

}
var selectedPhoto: BBPhoto1?

switch (selectedPhoto) {
        case kommunen {

        }

    case sagsbehandler{

        }
    }
```

but I get errors : "Use of unresolved identifier kommunen" and same messege but with Sagsbehandler.

How do I make it work ?

Comment: @Pointblaster But the point is to KNOW what i'm programing etc. KNOW what i want to seperate and make functions for. it makes it easiere to use names and not invent the dish agian. Also i postet this in 2014 ;)

Comment: Sorry Kenny forgot to check the post date. Your completely right, best wishes for you, hope that you're still pursuing the swift language :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code.

The first is that `selectedPhoto` is declared as optional, so you must unwrap it before using in a switch statement - for example using optional binding.

The second problem is that the syntax you're using is incorrect. In each `case` you have to specify the full name (including the type), followed by a colon:

```
case BBPhoto1.kommunen:
    // statements
```

but since the type can be inferred by the variable type used in the switch, you can ignore the enum type, but not the dot:

```
case .kommunen:
    // statements
```

Last, in swift a `switch` statements require that all cases are handled either explicitly (3 in your case) or using a `default` case covering all cases non explicitly handled in the `switch`.

A working version of your code would look like:

```
enum BBPhoto1: Int {
    case kommunen = 10
    case sagsbehandler = 20
    case festen = 30
}

var selectedPhoto: BBPhoto1?

if let selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto {
    switch (selectedPhoto) {
    case .kommunen:
        println(selectedPhoto.toRaw())

    case .sagsbehandler:
        println(selectedPhoto.toRaw())

    default:
        println("none")
    }
}
```

Note that, differently from other languages, the code in each case doesn't automatically fallthrough to the next case, so the `break` statement is not required - the only use case for it is when a case has no statement (a case with no statement is an error in swift), and in that case the `break` just acts as a placeholder and its meaning is 'do nothing'.

Suggested reading: [Conditional Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_199)

Comment: Hmm, not sure i understand why it haves to be in a if statement...
but i appreciate the answer and will accept it

Comment: Calling `fromRaw` returns an optional value because the raw value you pass might not be a valid one. In that case, you will receive `nil`. That is why you had to declare `selectedPhoto` as an optional. To use the value in the `switch` you have to unwrap the optional value. Here, @Antonio has used the optional binding syntax `if let`. This binds the non-optional value to the variable if it isn't `nil`. If you passed a bad value to `fromRaw` and your `selectedValue` is nil, then the block following `if let` will not be entered.

Comment: Thanks @vacawama for explaining in such a clear way :)

Comment: I also consider it more preferable to type `if let _ = selectedPhoto {` in this case to clarify the intension of checking for an optional and unwrap the optional via `selectedPhoto!` in the following scope. But this is just my personal taste.

Comment: @Antonio Can we put that within switch's condition so that don't write if statment ?

Comment: @Konstantin1990 you can, indirectly: leave `selectedPhoto` as optional, and do something like `case .Some(.kommunen)`. That doesn't replace the optional binding though